# Reading/writing pyarrow tensors from/to parquet files

Tags: numpy, parquet, tensor, pyarrow

In [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/index.html), what is the suggested way of writing a `pyarrow.Tensor` (e.g. created from a `numpy.ndarray`) to a Parquet file? Is it even possible without having to go through `pyarrow.Table` and `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: It's been a while. Did you find some interesting way to achieve this Martin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data model for Parquet is tabular, so somewhere the tensor/ndarray must get converted to a tabular form. We don't have any built-in convenience functions to help with this, but feel free to make specific feature requests on the issue tracker https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARROW

Comment: [ARROW-5645](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-5645), [ARROW-5819](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-5819)

Answer (score 3):

The Parquet format is optimised for tables with nested data, i.e. it expects that data is represented as named columns. This is a bit in contrast to the idea of n-dimensional columns. For tensors, it is better to choose a different format.